# "ERROR: Cannot add foreign key constraint" - Migration

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize.js

I have two migrations files, one to create a table of users and the other one of images. I want to add a new migration file to add the foreign key in the table of users so I write the next code in the migration file

```
module.exports = { 
 up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
 return queryInterface.addColumn('user','idImage',{
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  references: {
    model: 'image',
    key: 'id'
  }
}),}
```

The first two migrations runs correctly but in the third one it appears the following error "ERROR: Cannot add foreign key constraint".

I read that foreign keys can only be defined in createTable queries but I supose it has to be a solution for this because if not it wouldnt be performance and scalable.

Someone has any solution ?

Comment: is referenced table image a valid table name?

Comment: check for data types of foreign key column and id column in image

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error because of relationship data types are not matched.